# Jquery Error Trap Logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".submit").click(function() {
    if($(".firstname").val()=='' && $(".gender").val()==0){
      $(".regform input.firstname, .regform select.gender").css('border','3px solid red');
    }else {
      $(".regform input.firstname, .regform select.gender").css('border','2px solid #78bdca');
    }
    if($(".firstname").val()!='') {
      $(".steps.step3, .steps.step4, .steps.step5").fadeIn(1000).css({
        display: "block"
      }); 

      $(".submit").prop('value', 'Submit');
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
.steps {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}

.regform select {
 width: 380px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
 -moz-border-radius: 7px;
 border-radius: 7px;
 border: #78bdca 2px solid;
 font-family: 'quicksandregular';
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 12px 0 12px 12px;
 color: #78bdca;
 background: #fff url(/images/assets/hcd-dropdown.png) 96% 50% no-repeat;
 background-size: 15px auto;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: button;
 appearance: button;
 text-overflow: '';
}

.regform input {
 width: 380px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
 -moz-border-radius: 7px;
 border-radius: 7px;
 border: #78bdca 2px solid;
 font-family: 'quicksandregular';
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 12px 0 12px 12px;
 color: #78bdca;
}

.regform select[name=dobday], .regform select[name=dobmonth], .regform select[name=dobyear] {
  width: 124.5px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.steps.step3, .steps.step4, .steps.step5 {
 display: none;
}

.submit .myButton {
 -webkit-appearance: button;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 380px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'quicksandregular';
 font-size: 16px;
  height: 44px;
 outline: 0;
 border: none;
 background: rgba(120, 189, 202, .9);
 padding: 0;
}
```

I would like to ask for some help with a logic. I'm a newbie on JS

Logic:

If you click the submit button, if the 2 elements doesn't have any value, I make it on a red border(which i've achieved.) to emphasized the error. Now, when I put a value of one of the element said, I wanted to make a red border of the element left with no value.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".submit").click(function() {
  if($(".firstname").val()=='' && $(".gender").val()==0){
   $(".regform input.firstname, .regform select.gender").css('border','3px solid red');
  }else {
   $(".regform input.firstname, .regform select.gender").css('border','2px solid #78bdca');
  }
  if($(".firstname").val()!='') {
  $(".steps.step3, .steps.step4, .steps.step5").fadeIn(1000).css({
   display: "block",
   visibility: "visible"
  }); 

  $(".submit .myButton").prop('value', 'Submit');
  }
 }); 
});
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: The js code by itself, does not seem to be enough, could you add the HTML snippet that accompanies your code?

Comment: @chalarangelo i've inserted the html

Comment: your button has class "myButton" when it should be "submit"

Comment: I think you need `$(".submit .myButton").click(` to attach the event. Right now you are attaching it to the `div` not the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just check their input separately:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        // Check for firstname input state
        if($(".firstname").val()==''){
            // Not filled, change to red
            $(".regform input.firstname").css('border','3px solid red');
        }
        else{
            // Filled, change to blue
            $(".regform input.firstname").css('border','2px solid #78bdca');
        }
        // Check for gender input state
        if($(".gender").val()==0){
            // Not filled, change to red
            $(".regform select.gender").css('border','3px solid red');
        }
        else{
            // Filled, change to blue
            $(".regform select.gender").css('border','2px solid #78bdca');
        }
    }); 
});
```

So, each one of them will have its own checking condition and if filled out properly will turn blue, otherwise it will turn red. Also, a full example is in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efrotfb2/).

**P.S.:** I removed some bits from your Javascript/jQuery code as they were unclear to me in terms of functionality. Feel free to add them again where they should be.

**P.S.2:** In my Fiddle I also changed the `.submit` class from the `div` to `.submit-div` and added the `.submit` class to your button. If you would rather have it the original way, change back accordingly along with the code I provided!

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and store the DOM object.
on click of submit button, loop through the array , check it's value and apply the css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function() {
            // An array to store DOM object
            var inpElem = [$(".firstname"), $(".gender")]
            // Iterate through it and check it's value 
            inpElem.forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(item.val)
                if (item.val() == '') {
                    item.css('border', '3px solid red');
                } else {
                    item.css('border', '2px solid #78bdca');
                }
            })
            if ($(".firstname").val() != '') {
                $(".steps.step3, .steps.step4, .steps.step5").fadeIn(1000).css({
                    display: "block",
                    visibility: "visible"
                });

                $(".submit .myButton").prop('value', 'Submit');
            }
        });
    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1yy145pq/)

Comment: this is also good but complex one! thank you @user2181397 for your help! appreciated your logic!